# Vaadin: select item in tree on mouse down

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

Currently the item selection in `Tree` is happening on mouse click (up and down). Is it possible to make it on mouse down?

I've tried to implement it via custom extension, but haven't succeed: the mouse down interceptor knows nothing about the actual tree item where the event happened, so it can't trigger the `tree#select` method on the particular entry. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need it on mouse down instead of click?

Comment: Because I have drag and drop in my tree and currently one must first click the item to select it and then drag instead of just dragging it without previous click.